# how works $(function(){}); in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I like to know how works or what means(?) when you define a function in the selector in jquery like this.

```
$(function(){code,code})
```

because with jquery-ui you can (or must.. I'm really new with this library) set accordion with this code

```
$(function(){
    // Accordion
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
        function(){$(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');},
        function(){$(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    });

});
```

> Source: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

And I have a problem setting accodions inside tabs(also with jquery-ui), but I cann't find why works buggy, and I think that maybe can I fix the problem understanding this behavior.

And pretty sure that I doesn't undestood quiet right the selector in jquery, hope you can help me. Thanks in advance, by the way sorry about my poorly english.

Comment: Keep in mind the $(document).ready(function{ code })}; is an EVENT handler for the document ready event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(somefunction)` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(somefunction)`. So what you're doing with `$(function{})` is defining an anonymous function that will run once the document loads.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){ /*...*/ });
```

Is the same as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*...*/ });
```

Basically, it just holds off code-execution until the document is ready. It's just an anonymous function. You see the same thing in your `$.hover()` call, which takes two anonymous functions - one to determine the "enter" logic, and the other to determine the "exit" logic.

```
$(".foo").hover(
  function(){ alert("You entered!"); },
  function(){ alert("You exited!!"); }
);
```

Sometimes these function bring with them different localized variables you can use. For instance, if you were to iterate through many elements using jQuery's `$.each()` method:

```
$(".foo").each(function(i,o){
  alert("Currently on " + i); // Currently on 0, Currently on 1...
});
```

You can see that we've got two variables `i` and `o`, available to us here. `i` is the index of the current element being iterated, and `o` is a reference to the element itself.

Comment: Good explanation on the $(function(){}).
I wonder, are not these covered in Jquery api.

Answer (score 0):

They've just written it out in a way you've probably not seen before. The hover method takes two possible functions, one for entering and one for exiting. Sometimes written:

```
$('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(function(){
  //stuff to do on mouseenter
  $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
}, function(){
  //stuff to do on mouseleave
  $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1

Answer (score 0):

`$(function () {})` is short-hand for `jQuery(function () {})`, which is short-hand for `$(document).ready(function () {})`. I.e. it binds a function to the Document's Ready event, i.e. this code will get executed when the document finished loading. It's what you should always do.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3